# How to mock construction of new objects under JDK 1.4?

Tags: java, mocking, jdk1.4

I'll looking about mocking of constructor calls in tested method. Something like http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

The problem is that I'm working under JDK 1.4 (this is requirement of customer). I tried to use Retrotranslator for PowerMock, but it seems that I can do nothing about required use of annotations @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest for running example.

Maybe somebody can advise me the mocking framework which works under JDK 1.4 and can mock construction of new objects?

Answer (score 0):

JMock 1 for JDK 1.3 and above
http://www.jmock.org/download.html

Easymock has a version compatible with JDK 1.3 I think
http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymock/files/EasyMock/1.2/easymock1.2_Java1.3.zip/download

Comment: EasyMock hasn't required feature. I'm not sure about JMock 1 but it seems that it hasn't too.